# how to register generic decorator for collection of eventhandlers implementing the same interface with Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac, mediatr

So we have two Eventhandlers listening to the same event.
A decorator is supposed to create a LifteTimeScope, resolve the decorated eventhandler and invoke the Handle method of the decorated eventhandler.
I found lot of examples of doing this with CommandHandlers. But there its easier since there is only one Handler per Command. Not many.
So the Question is how to register the event handlers and the decorator in autofac!

```
class EventHandlerA : IAsyncNotification<AnEvent>
{ 
     public void Handle(AnEvent theEvent)
     {
     }
}

class EventHandlerB : IAsyncNotification<AnEvent>
{ 
     public void Handle(AnEvent theEvent)
     {
     }
}

/// <summary>
///  Wraps inner Notification Handler in Autofac Lifetime scope named 
     PerEventHandlerScope"
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TNotification"></typeparam>
public class LifetimeScopeEventHandlerDecorator<TNotification> :
    IAsyncNotificationHandler<TNotification> where TNotification : class, 
              IAsyncNotification
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;
    private readonly Type _decoratedType;

    /// <summary>
    /// Const Name of Scope that dependencies can Match using       
     PerMatchingLifeTimeScope(LifetimeScopeEventHandlerDecorator.ScopeName)
    /// </summary>
    public const string ScopeName = LifeTimeScopeKeys.PerHandlerKey;

    /// <summary>
    /// constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="scope"></param>
    public LifetimeScopeEventHandlerDecorator( ILifetimeScope scope, Type 
          decoratedType )
    {
        _decoratedType = decoratedType;
        _scope = scope;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wraps inner Notification Handler in Autofac Lifetime scope
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="notification"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task Handle( TNotification notification )
    {
        using ( var perHandlerScope = _scope.BeginLifetimeScope( 
         LifeTimeScopeKeys.PerHandlerKey ) )
        {
            var decoratedHandler =
   perHandlerScope.ResolveKeyed<IAsyncNotificationHandler<TNotification>>( 
              "IAsyncNotificationHandlerKey" );
            await decoratedHandler.Handle( notification );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the heading :-) *I will repeat in question thx